# Why do I have the wrong number of arguments when calling main through reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a Class object and I want to invoke a static method. I have the following code.

```
Method m = cls.getMethod("main", String[].class);
System.out.println(m.getParameterTypes().length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m.getParameterTypes()));
System.out.println(m.getName());
m.invoke(null, new String[]{});
```

This prints:

> ```
> 1
> [class [Ljava.lang.String;]
> main
> ```

But then it then it throws:

```
IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will have to use

```
m.invoke(null, (Object)new String[]{});
```

The [`invoke(Object, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method accepts a `Object...`. **(Correction)** The `String[]` array passed is used as that `Object[]` and is empty, so it has no elements to pass to your method invocation. By casting it to `Object`, you are saying this is the only element in the wrapping `Object[]`.

This is because of array covariance. You can do

```
public static void method(Object[] a) {}
...
method(new String[] {});
```

Because a `String[]` is a `Object[]`.

```
System.out.println(new String[]{} instanceof Object[]); // returns true
```

Alternatively, you can wrap your `String[]` in an `Object[]`

```
m.invoke(null, new Object[]{new String[]{}});
```

The method will then use the elements in the `Object[]` as arguments for your method invocation.

<sub>Careful with the StackOverflowError of calling `main(..)`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

And you can do this:

```
Method m = cls.getMethod("main", String[].class);
System.out.println(m.getParameterTypes().length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m.getParameterTypes()));
System.out.println(m.getName());
String[] a = new String[1];
m.invoke(null, a);
```