# Avoid incorrect number of arguments when invoking a Java class main method from Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, reflection, program-entry-point

From a Groovy class method I am trying to invoke the main function of a Java class in the default package (I know not optimal but am using legacy code).

I have tried using a modified version from the Java reflection tutorial thusly:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(className)
Class[] argTypes = new Class[] { String[].class }
Method main = c.getDeclaredMethod("main", argTypes)
String[] mainArgs = Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 0, args.length)
main.invoke(null, mainArgs)
```

This throws an IllegalArgumentException as follows:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

Other items to note:

- `argTypes[0]` is `class [Ljava.lang.String`
- `main` is `public static void AClassName.main(java.lang.String[])`
- `mainArgs` is `java.lang.String[6]`

Is there a different way of doing this that is needed in Groovy versus Java? Otherwise how to invoke main from a default package class?

Comment: In ordinary Java, this would fail as well. And it’s unnecessary complicated; you can just write, `Class<?> c = Class.forName(className); Method main = c.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class); main.invoke(null, (Object)args);` There’s no need for manual array creation and the `copyOfRange` is obsolete. Of course, you could even write it as a single statement without the intermediate variables, `Class.forName(className) .getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class) .invoke(null, (Object)args);`

Answer (score 2):

Found it...  Given this Java class in the default package

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(List.of(args));
  }
}
```

and with a little bit of help from this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/22022402/6509

We can do this (which is your code, slightly Groovified, with an Object[] wrapper round the String[] as per that other question):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method

Class c = Class.forName("Main")
Class[] argTypes = [String[]]
Method main = c.getDeclaredMethod("main", argTypes)

String[] mainArgs = ['hello', 'tim']
main.invoke(null, new Object[] { mainArgs })
```

And when we run the Groovy script, we get the output:

```
➜ groovy test.groovy
[hello, tim]
```

This is working for `Groovy Version: 3.0.8 JVM: 11.0.6 Vendor: Azul Systems, Inc. OS: Mac OS X` btw, in case you see different :-)

Comment: Thanks Tim. It seems like the [String[]] and Object[] did the trick.